# Open XML data lables

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am creating a bar chart with openxml and need to have the x axis labels on the bottom of the chart rotated at a 45 degree angle.  Using the documentation for openxml barcharts I cannot figure out how to displays the labels. Below is the function I use to create the chart. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
    public static void InsertChartInSpreadsheet(string docName, string worksheetName, string title,
    System.Data.DataTable data)
    {
        // Open the document for editing.
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true))
        {
            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().
            Where(s => s.Name == worksheetName);
            if (sheets.Count() == 0)
            {
                // The specified worksheet does not exist.
                return;
            }
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheets.First().Id);

            // Add a new drawing to the worksheet.
            DrawingsPart drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Drawing() { Id = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart) });
            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

            // Add a new chart and set the chart language to English-US.
            ChartPart chartPart = drawingsPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();
            chartPart.ChartSpace = new ChartSpace();
            chartPart.ChartSpace.Append(new EditingLanguage() { Val = new StringValue("en-US") });
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart chart = chartPart.ChartSpace.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart>(
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Chart());

            // Create a new bar chart.
            PlotArea plotArea = chart.AppendChild<PlotArea>(new PlotArea());
            Layout layout = plotArea.AppendChild<Layout>(new Layout());
            BarChart barChart = plotArea.AppendChild<BarChart>(new BarChart(new BarDirection() { Val = new EnumValue<BarDirectionValues>(BarDirectionValues.Column) },
                new DataLabels(new DataLabelPosition { Val = new EnumValue<DataLabelPositionValues>(DataLabelPositionValues.InsideBase) }
            )));

            uint i = 0;

            // Iterate through each key in the Dictionary collection and add the key to the chart Series
            // and add the corresponding value to the chart Values.
            foreach (DataRow r in data.Rows)
            {
                BarChartSeries barChartSeries = barChart.AppendChild<BarChartSeries>(new BarChartSeries(new Index()
                {
                    Val = new UInt32Value(i)
                },
                    new Order() { Val = new UInt32Value(i) },
                    new SeriesText(new NumericValue() { Text = r[2].ToString().Trim() }
                    )));

                StringLiteral strLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild<CategoryAxisData>(new CategoryAxisData()).AppendChild<StringLiteral>(new StringLiteral());
                strLit.Append(new PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value(1U) });
                strLit.AppendChild<StringPoint>(new StringPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(0U) }).Append(new NumericValue(title));

                NumberLiteral numLit = barChartSeries.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values>(
                    new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.Values()).AppendChild<NumberLiteral>(new NumberLiteral());
                numLit.Append(new FormatCode("General"));
                numLit.Append(new PointCount() { Val = new UInt32Value(1U) });
                numLit.AppendChild<NumericPoint>(new NumericPoint() { Index = new UInt32Value(0u) }).Append(new NumericValue(r[8].ToString().Trim()));

                i++;
            }
            barChart.Append(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) });
            barChart.Append(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) });

            // Add the Category Axis.
            CategoryAxis catAx = plotArea.AppendChild<CategoryAxis>(new CategoryAxis(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112u) }, new Scaling(new Orientation()
            {
                Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.
                    OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
            }),
                new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<AxisPositionValues>(AxisPositionValues.Bottom) },
                new TickLabelPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<TickLabelPositionValues>(TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo) },
                new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768U) },
                new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossesValues>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
                new AutoLabeled() { Val = new BooleanValue(true) },
                new LabelAlignment() { Val = new EnumValue<LabelAlignmentValues>(LabelAlignmentValues.Left) },
                new LabelOffset() { Val = new UInt16Value((ushort)100) }));

             // Add the Value Axis.
             ValueAxis valAx = plotArea.AppendChild<ValueAxis>(new ValueAxis(new AxisId() { Val = new UInt32Value(48672768u) },
             new Scaling(new Orientation()
                {
                    Val = new EnumValue<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues>(
                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.OrientationValues.MinMax)
                }),
                new AxisPosition() { Val = new EnumValue<AxisPositionValues>(AxisPositionValues.Left) },
                new MajorGridlines(),
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.NumberingFormat()
                {
                    FormatCode = new StringValue("General"),
                    SourceLinked = new BooleanValue(true)

                }, new TickLabelPosition()
                {
                    Val = new EnumValue<TickLabelPositionValues>
                        (TickLabelPositionValues.NextTo)
                }, new CrossingAxis() { Val = new UInt32Value(48650112U) },
                new Crosses() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossesValues>(CrossesValues.AutoZero) },
                new CrossBetween() { Val = new EnumValue<CrossBetweenValues>(CrossBetweenValues.Between) }));

            // Save the chart part.
            chartPart.ChartSpace.Save();

            // Position the chart on the worksheet using a TwoCellAnchor object.
            drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = new WorksheetDrawing();
            TwoCellAnchor twoCellAnchor = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.AppendChild<TwoCellAnchor>(new TwoCellAnchor());
            twoCellAnchor.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.FromMarker(new ColumnId("0"),
                new ColumnOffset("581025"),
                new RowId("3"),
                new RowOffset("114300")));
            twoCellAnchor.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.ToMarker(new ColumnId("17"),
                new ColumnOffset("276225"),
                new RowId("32"),
                new RowOffset("0")));

            // Append a GraphicFrame to the TwoCellAnchor object.
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame graphicFrame =
                twoCellAnchor.AppendChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.
            Drawing.Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame>(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.
            Spreadsheet.GraphicFrame());
            graphicFrame.Macro = "";

            graphicFrame.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameProperties(
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = new UInt32Value(2u), Name = "Chart 1" },
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties()));

            graphicFrame.Append(new Transform(new Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                                                    new Extents() { Cx = 0L, Cy = 0L }));

            graphicFrame.Append(new Graphic(new GraphicData(new ChartReference() { Id = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart) }) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" }));

            twoCellAnchor.Append(new ClientData());

            // Save the WorksheetDrawing object.
            drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Save();

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

place in category Axis construtor

```
new C.Delete { Val = false },

new C.TextProperties(new BodyProperties { Rotation = -5400000, Vertical = TextVerticalValues.Horizontal },
                    new ListStyle(),
                    new Paragraph(new ParagraphProperties(new DefaultRunProperties(), new EndParagraphRunProperties { Language = "en-US" }))),
```